# System-Level Average Power/Current Measurements

Tags: current-measurement

I have a question regarding probes/methods when measuring system-level average power/current.

The system consists of microcontrollers and multiple valves, including solenoid valves. My plan is to use two channels/probes to measure the voltage across a 1-ohm in series resistor on the O-Scope when the system is on, as described [using differential probe setup](https://articles.saleae.com/oscilloscopes/how-to-measure-current-with-an-oscilloscope).

I am aware of current differential probes which are specifically used for current measurement. Since the entire system is operating under 12VDC power supply, I do not think current probes are necessary. Would my planned setup with regular probes work for the electromechanical system?

Comment: if you indeed make sure you don't have a ground loop, you should be fine.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks so much for your reply! I would like to ask another question: is it correct for me to measure the RMS of V^2 across the resistor, and then divide it by R to get the average power?

Comment: sounds reasonable, but beware that if your current draw changes faster than you can square-root-and-mean, then you might not be measuring everything.